# NSIS: Custom page on StateChanged

Tags: installation, nsis

I have a some different license pages with check box on it. The `Next` button should be disabled if check box is unchecked. Is there an event that I can use if checkbox state changed? Here is my code of one of this

```
var Window
var labelDescription
var checkBoxIsUserAgree

Function CreateCustomLicense1
  nsDialogs::Create 1018
  Pop $Window

  GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT
  EnableWindow $0 0
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 13u 22u 270u 96u "Description"
  Pop $labelDescription
  ${NSD_CreateCheckBox} 10u 110u 100u 15u "I Agree"
  $checkBoxIsUserAgree
FunctionEnd

Function ShowCustomLicence1
  Call CreateCustomLicense1
  nsDialogs::Show
Function

Function .oncheckBoxIsUserAgreeStateChanged ; what event I can use for track checkbox state changing
 EnableWindow $0 1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: It helps if you post code that actually compiles! Reading the documentation first might be a good idea as well...

Comment: @Anders I try to find answer in documentation, but I was looking something wrong. I thought that it should be something like .onSelectedChanged for global page. I couldn't imagine than I can use ${NSD_...} as a function. Thx!

Comment: NSD_ are helper macros, some just call nsDialogs::xyz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in NSIS license page supports a checkbox and can be used multiple times but if you insist on creating a custom page you just have to add a [on*](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html#mref-onback) handler:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Var checkBoxIsUserAgree

Function ShowCustomLicence1
  nsDialogs::Create 1018
  Pop $1

  GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
  EnableWindow $0 0
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 13u 22u 270u 90u "Description"
  Pop $1
  ${NSD_CreateCheckBox} 10u 110u 100u 15u "I Agree"
  Pop $checkBoxIsUserAgree
  ${NSD_OnClick} $checkBoxIsUserAgree oncheckBoxIsUserAgreeStateChanged1

  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd


Function oncheckBoxIsUserAgreeStateChanged1
  Pop $1 ; Throw away parameter
  ${NSD_GetState} $checkBoxIsUserAgree $1
  EnableWindow $0 $1
FunctionEnd

Page Custom ShowCustomLicence1
Page InstFiles
```